# Quickly searchable synonym terms

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to keep in DB some terms. However, they can have multiple synonyms. The idea of synonyms is simply to be replaced by the actual (original) terms.

For example, I have a term "copywriting", but this term may have multiple practically used synonyms like "web-writing" and "webwriting".

I may have them in a seperate table, with a reference to the `original_term_id`. With such solution, I can easily check out for all the terms:

```
SELECT * FROM terms WHERE term = "webwriting"

(result would be 0 - as "webwriting is a synonym in DB)
```

So if nothing has been found, I can search also the other table:

```
SELECT * FROM synonyms WHERE term = "webwriting"

(result would be 1 - as "webwriting is placed in this table)
```

Then I replace "webwriting" with "copywriting" thanks to `original_term_id` column in the `synonyms` table.

Since I may have indexes on the `term` column, the presented way of achieving that is quick and simple.

This is a simple solution. Is there any sensible alternative *without* introducing a new table (synonyms), while the solution remained quick and simple?

Comment: I just don't get what your question is.  Can you be clearer on what results you want?

Comment: See my comment under the Gordon Linoff reply. It explains what I want and what alternative I consider.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the terms associated with a term or synonym, you can `join` the two together:

```
select t.*
from terms t left join
     synonyms s
     on s.term = t.term and s.synonym = ?
where t.term = ? or s.term is not null;
```

You can also simply require that each term is its own synonym.  In that case, the query is simpler (and possibly more efficient):

```
select t.*
from terms t join
     synonyms s
     on s.term = t.term 
where s.synonym = ?;
```

Comment: Thanks. I wonder whether I should keep the `synonym` table (being the original solution), or should I go with an alternative one - e.g. keep both terms and their synonyms in the same table... the drawback is that the term record should have additional information, which are redundant to a synonym (being a simple reference to another term).

Comment: @forsberg . . . Keep the synonym table.  Be sure that all terms are in the table as their own synonyms.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more what are the cons, perhaps giving the answer to the question?